# how to import XML file to mysql db?

Tags: php, xml

Can anyone help with converting data from an XML document into an associative array? I'm running into issues given that the XML structure.
the code make loop, but repeat the same node (first node in xml file).
this code insert into database four rows (all them the same row).
How make the code goto to the other node in the xml.

/////////////////////////////XML FILE//////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <property>   
        <id>2</id>
        <type>2</type>
        <rent_type>1</rent_type>
        <cid>1</cid>
        <locid>2</locid>
        <stid>2</stid>
        <cnid>2</cnid>
        <locality>2</locality>
        <state>costa blanca</state>
        <country>spain</country>
        <office_id>1</office_id>
        <mls_id>2d2</mls_id>
        <mls_agent>2</mls_agent>
        <viewad>1</viewad>
        <viewbooking>1</viewbooking>
        <unit_num>mmmmm</unit_num>
        <street_num>nnnn</street_num>
        <address2>mmmbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b bbm</address2>
        <postcode></postcode>
        <county>dd</county>
        <price>222222222.00</price>
        <showprice>1</showprice>
        <freq>0</freq>
        <bond>0.00</bond>
        <closeprice>2222222222.00</closeprice>
        <priceview>3</priceview>
        <age>5</age>
        <landtype>1</landtype>
        <frontage></frontage>
        <depth></depth>
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>3</id>
        <type>2</type>
        <rent_type>0</rent_type>
        <cid>1</cid>
        <locid>0</locid>
        <stid>0</stid>
        <cnid>0</cnid>
        <locality></locality>
        <state></state>
        <country></country>
        <office_id></office_id>
        <mls_id>3d3</mls_id>
        <mls_agent></mls_agent>
        <viewad>0</viewad>
        <viewbooking>0</viewbooking>
        <unit_num>mmmmm</unit_num>
        <street_num>nnnn</street_num>
        <address2>mmmm</address2>
        <postcode></postcode>
        <county>dd</county>
        <price>3333333333.00</price>
        <showprice>1</showprice>
        <freq>0</freq>
        <bond>0.00</bond>
        <closeprice>333333.00</closeprice>
        <priceview></priceview>
        <age></age>
        <landtype></landtype>
        <frontage></frontage>
        <depth></depth>
     </property>
    <property>
        <id>4</id>
        <type>0</type>
        <rent_type>0</rent_type>
        <cid>1</cid>
        <locid>0</locid>
        <stid>0</stid>
        <cnid>0</cnid>
        <locality></locality>
        <state></state>
        <country></country>
        <office_id></office_id>
        <mls_id>4d4</mls_id>
        <mls_agent></mls_agent>
        <viewad>0</viewad>
        <viewbooking>0</viewbooking>
        <unit_num>mmmmm</unit_num>
        <street_num>nnnn</street_num>
        <address2>mmmm</address2>
        <postcode></postcode>
        <county>dd</county>
        <price>444444444444444.00</price>
        <showprice>1</showprice>
        <freq>0</freq>
        <bond>0.00</bond>
        <closeprice>4444444444444444444.00</closeprice>
        <priceview></priceview>
        <age></age>
        <landtype></landtype>
        <frontage></frontage>
        <depth></depth>
    </property>
   <property>
        <id>5</id>
        <type>0</type>
        <rent_type>0</rent_type>
        <cid>1</cid>
        <locid>0</locid>
        <stid>0</stid>
        <cnid>0</cnid>
        <locality></locality>
        <state></state>
        <country></country>
        <office_id></office_id>
        <mls_id>5d5</mls_id>
        <mls_agent></mls_agent>
        <viewad>0</viewad>
        <viewbooking>0</viewbooking>
        <unit_num>mmmmm</unit_num>
        <street_num>nnnn</street_num>
        <address2>mmmm</address2>
        <postcode></postcode>
        <county>dd</county>
        <price>55555555555555.00</price>
        <showprice>1</showprice>
        <freq>0</freq>
        <bond>0.00</bond>
        <closeprice>55555555555.00</closeprice>
        <priceview></priceview>
        <age></age>
        <landtype></landtype>
        <frontage></frontage>
        <depth></depth>
    </property>
</root>
```

//////////////////////////////PHP CODE/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');

echo "starting<br />";

//mysql connection
...
echo "connected to DB<br /><br />";

$url = "s_property1.xml";
    $xmlfgc = file_get_contents($url);
    $xmlitem = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlfgc);
    echo "xml loaded<br /><br />";

foreach ($xmlitem->property as $xml) {
//for ($i=0;$i ;){
    $id          = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->id);
    $type        = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->type);
    $rent_type   = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->rent_type);
    $cid         = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->cid);
    $locid       = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->locid);
    $stid        = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->stid);
    $cnid        = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->cnid);
    $locality    = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->locality);
    $state       = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->state);
    $country     = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->country);
    $office_id   = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->office_id);
    $mls_id      = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->mls_id);
    $mls_agent   = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->mls_agent);
    $viewad      = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->viewad);
    $viewbooking = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->viewbooking);
    $unit_num    = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->unit_num);
    $street_num  = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->street_num);
    $address2    = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->address2);
    $postcode    = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->postcode);    
    $county      = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->county);
    $price       = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->price);
    $showprice   = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->showprice);
    $freq        = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->freq);
    $bond        = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->bond);
    $closeprice  = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->closeprice);    
    $priceview   = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->priceview);
    $age         = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->age);
    $landtype    = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->landtype);
    $frontage    = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->frontage);
    $depth       = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->depth);

echo "xml parsed<br /><br />";

$xmldata = array();

$xmldata[] = '("' . $id. '", "' . $type . '", "' . $rent_type. '", "' . $cid . '", "' . $locid . '", "' . $stid . '", "' . $cnid . '", 
       "' . $locality . '", "' . $state . '", "' . $country . '", "' . $office_id . '", "' . $mls_id . '", "' . $mls_agent . '",
       "' . $viewad . '", "' . $viewbooking . '", "' . $unit_num . '", "' . $street_num . '", "' . $address2 . '", "' . $postcode . '",
       "' . $county . '", "' . $price . '", "' . $showprice . '", "' . $freq . '", "' . $bond . '", "' . $closeprice . '",
       "' . $priceview . '" ,"' . $age . '", "' . $landtype . '", "' . $frontage . '", "' . $depth . '")';

//insert into databse                     
$query = 'INSERT INTO gitfd_ezrealty ( id, type, rent_type, cid, locid, stid, cnid, locality, state, country, office_id, mls_id, mls_agent,
               viewad, viewbooking, unit_num, street_num, address2, postcode, county, price, showprice, freq, bond, closeprice, priceview,
               age, landtype, frontage, depth)
    VALUES' . implode(',', $xmldata);

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "inserted into mysql<br /><br />";

    print_r($xmldata);

}
```

?>

but the id is auto_increment.

the output of this code = 4 rows into db + {starting
connected to DB

xml loaded

xml parsed

inserted into mysql

Array ( [0] => ("", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "costa blanca", "spain", "1", "2d2", "2", "1", "1", "mmmmm", "nnnn", "mmmbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b bbm", "", "dd", "222222222.00", "1", "0", "0.00", "2222222222.00", "3" ,"5", "1", "", "") ) xml parsed

inserted into mysql

Array ( [0] => ("", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "costa blanca", "spain", "1", "2d2", "2", "1", "1", "mmmmm", "nnnn", "mmmbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b bbm", "", "dd", "222222222.00", "1", "0", "0.00", "2222222222.00", "3" ,"5", "1", "", "") ) xml parsed

inserted into mysql

Array ( [0] => ("", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "costa blanca", "spain", "1", "2d2", "2", "1", "1", "mmmmm", "nnnn", "mmmbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b bbm", "", "dd", "222222222.00", "1", "0", "0.00", "2222222222.00", "3" ,"5", "1", "", "") ) xml parsed

inserted into mysql

Array ( [0] => ("", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "costa blanca", "spain", "1", "2d2", "2", "1", "1", "mmmmm", "nnnn", "mmmbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb b bbm", "", "dd", "222222222.00", "1", "0", "0.00", "2222222222.00", "3" ,"5", "1", "", "") )

Records inserted: 1 }

Comment: Not sure you can use foreach ($xmlitem->property as $xml) that way, try this instead: http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.children.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id          = mysql_real_escape_string($xmlitem->property->id);
```

Use

```
$id          = mysql_real_escape_string($xml->id);
```

instead

Comment: The Problem Solved. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a class `XML2Array` in the link which makes it easy to convert xml to array and vice versa.[Xml2Array](http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-xml-to-array-in-php-xml2array/)

Usage:

```
$array = XML2Array::createArray(file_get_contents('path/to/xml-file.xml'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
```

You should be able to loop through the object.

Alternatively review MySQLs solution to loading in XML files: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html